# Qt versions for architectures mips, arm, x86 are missing

Tags: android, qt, mobile, architecture, arm

I am trying to use Qt-Project V.5.1 to develop an App for Android. After installing `qt-windows-opensource-5.1.0-msvc2012_opengl-x86_64-offline` installer with every component selectable during the installation, I try to set it up for android building.

In the Qt Creator, I open tools->options->Android and fill in my Android SDK, Android NDK, Ant und opnJDK Locations and tick the "automatically create Kits for Android tool chains." Checkbox

Here I get a warning saying:

`Qt versions for architectures mips, arm, x86 are missing. To add the Qt versions, select Options > Build & Run >Qt versions.`

When I go to the Qt Versions Tab, there is neither an option for Android nor an option for mips arm or x86. (In fact there is just the QT 5.1.0 MSVC2012 OpenGl 64 Bit option). The Add Button only gives me the opportunity to specify a qmake file. The only one of those I can find is the one already referenced for the "QT 5.1.0 MSVC2012 OpenGl 64 Bit" option.

Can anyone tell me how to get the Android Option in the Build and Run Tab?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you will have to build your own package.  Most people using  Qt Windows don't want **Android**, **MIPS** or **ARM** support and would balk at the extra code.  It will be part of the Qt configure process; the windows release was configured without it.

Comment: Did you download API level 17/18 in the sdk? Is your emulator working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the "qt-windows-opensource-5.1.0-msvc2012_opengl-x86_64-offline" package, you only have binaries to develop for Windows.

You should check out [the QT download page](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2) today, there is a "Qt 5.1.1 for Android (Windows 32-bit, 716 MB) " package, which includes binaries to develop for Android. Or you can build from sources.

Comment: what if I want to use the same installation to develop to iOS?

Comment: @Juster: Due to Apple's restrictions/requirements, iOS development can only be done on a Mac. However, note that the code you already have will likely work on iOS without any code changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should download the online installer and when you get to choose components for installation make sure to choose the arm and Android ones, alongside any others you may need. I would recommend you download the offline qt installer (such as [this](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.10/5.10.0/) one here, you only need the ~2G .exe file) which gets packaged with everything and install/uninstall what you need. This is because the online installer and its repositories are a mess, often behaving erratically and you will get server errors until you get lucky and your whole installation goes through fine one quiet day.